# how to set UIDatePicker interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

I want to change UIDatePicker's interface, like: YYYY MM dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you can set on UIDatePicker is the [picker mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode), to time, date, time and date or countdown timer (for when you want to pick a quantity of time rather than an absolute clock time). The order of fields is then selected according to the user's locale. You can't set it yourself.